# How to import (stream) data in Drupal and save the visualization as nodes - similar to datamasher.org)?

Tags: 7, nodes, charts, database

I am working on a data visualization Drupal website. I am looking for a functionality close to [datamasher.org](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/datamasher-us-government-data-sets/), a site that was built using Drupal.

But I cannot find a way that would allow me to create the same functionality.

**My Question**: How to import data/stream data in a Drupal site and save the visualization as nodes?

Comment: Maybe you can use yahoo charts, you can send the values from a custom code and get the result. try this http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/charts/

Answer (score 1):

Nodes arent the best for storing data as such. I would suggest the [data module](http://drupal.org/project/data) for storing the datasets. (support for import via feeds is [underway](http://drupal.org/node/1551430))
To display some results and charts there is several ways - have a look at [forena](http://drupal.org/project/forena) for example. You could then create a node type that would save the parameter values for forena reports and upon node node display show the report. Similar functionality can be achevied vith views (not so much fomratting though).

Comment: Are there any other modules to do something similar ?

Comment: views together with some charting such as [Google chart](http://drupal.org/project/chart). Did you try forena ? its really good :)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd use the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module, you can use its **[Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) integration to create nodes** using Forena [data blocks](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.data#datablocks) and/or reports. In other words: Forena can be used as a feeds importer, which enables [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) to go read from al kinds of database tables, **external databases**, etc. which Feeds out-of-the-box does not support.

Forena's [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363) includes a child page [Video demos and tutorials](https://www.drupal.org/node/2360187) containing a link also about [using Forena to import data and reports based on data as drupal nodes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bg4P747DmE8). That video also demonstrates the creation of charts, so not just tabular reports, which seems pretty close (or identical?) to what you're looking for.

**Disclosure**: I'm a co-maintainer of Forena.